# working on multiple loops

Tags: php, loops

i have an array with multiple user id receiving from another page through header function

```
$Values= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['vals']));
```

this line give me such array

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 )
```

by using for each loop i am using each user id to retrieve data from database table and displaying into html table with following code

```
 //displaying data into tables -->
$Values= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['vals']));
if(isset($Values))
{
foreach($Values as $user_id)
{
     $prevCon['where'] = $user_id;
     $prevUser = $user->getRowss($prevCon);
     while($row = $prevUser->fetch_assoc())
     {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['country_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['city_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NIC'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

  }
}
}
else
{
echo " no data to display";
}
```

but my loop runs for 36 time each entry against one user id is being display for 6 times and then another user id is used again for 6 times

please do help me i want to display one entry for each user id

Comment: what does `$prevCon['where']` do? and where it being set..? why does it for-each then while inside? care to elaborate a bit..?

Comment: in function getrowss $prevCon['where'] is use to build query with where clause and for each is use each user id and while is use to display data in html column

Comment: Double check that `$Values` contains the data you want. If that doesn't do it, then it may have to do with the query itself.

Comment: run `var_dump($user->getRowss($prevCon));` after this line and see what it prints. My bet is also on the query.

Comment: it is giving me nothing and class of xdebug-error xe-fatal-error

Comment: it is giving me this C:\wamp64\www\cm\admin.html:26:
object(mysqli_result)[7]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 19
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 6
  public 'type' => int 0 for 6 times

Comment: What is `$prevCon` after you assign the user_id?